# In Linux how to loop-back the internal traffic that's destined to the server's own NATed public IP?

Tags: linux, networking, router, iptables, nat

By internal I mean only the traffic originating within the server itself (not LAN or other servers). I have a cloud VM where the Public IP provided by the cloud vendor is not directly attached to the VM. Lets assume the Public IP is `8.8.8.8`. The actual IP of the VM is `192.168.1.2`. There's a service listening on `192.168.1.2:443`. The public clients would be able to reach it via `8.8.8.8:443`. The server's own clients are able to reach it via both `192.168.1.2:443` and `8.8.8.8:443`.

I am assuming if the servers's own client makes a request to `8.8.8.8` it would first go to the server's default gateway then the gateway would NAT it and forward it to back to `192.168.1.2`. So my question is, if an internal client makes a request to `8.8.8.8`, how can it be forwarded directly to `192.168.1.2` without the traffic ever leaving the server, while the client is still thinking that it is talking to `8.8.8.8`.

OS version is Debian 11 (Kernel 5.10.0-26-cloud-amd64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add identical NAT rules to the server's own firewall. You need to place them in the 'OUTPUT' chain instead of the usual 'PREROUTING' (however, still in the 'nat' table). For example, in nftables:

```
table ip nat {
    chain output {
        type nat hook output priority dstnat;
        ip daddr 8.8.8.8 tcp dport 443 dnat to 192.168.1.2
    }
}
```

The iptables equivalent would most likely be:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 8.8.8.8 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT ...
```

Comment: Will it work with just a dnat? In this case, wouldn't the reply look like it is coming from `192.168.1.2` instead of `8.8.8.8`? Would clients that made the request to `8.8.8.8` accept that?

Comment: iptables' conntrack automatically applies the reverse translation for flows that are affected by any kind of NAT. (It's how private address masquerading works on most home routers.)